# How to "switch my Python" to pip update the package copy that my IDLE accesses?

Tags: command-line, python

I have an Anaconda installation of Python as well as an installation that comes when downloading Python and IDLE from [Python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and I use both of them.

For my Anaconda python I can use `pip install --upgrade PackageName` to update a package by just typing that line into iTerm.

For my "IDLE Python" I have had help updating the copy of the same package that IDLE imports. They "temporarily switched my Python", updated the package with pip, then "un-switched" it.

This worked nicely and I'd like to do it again. From my description is it possible to decipher what actually happened and to suggest the lines that might do this?

If there are other ways to do this, seeing those would also be appreciated, but I'd like to try this method specifically.

Comment: Why use both and why use pip to update anaconda surely better to use conda

Comment: @Mark I use both; it's purely a matter of personal taste. I'm just fond of IDLE's GUI and for some kinds of editing tasks I find the way the cursor works easier for me, or perhaps I'm just sentimental. I use conda for installations where it's appropriate, and pip for [non-conda packages](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#installing-non-conda-packages); an example would be [Skyfield](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/). You can see the developer recommends first installing an Anaconda distribution, then pip install Skyfield.

Comment: Today, "I'd like the newest Skyfield in my IDLE to match my Anaconda's." Sounds funny I know; can you help? Thanks!

Comment: I've just asked a version of this in SO: [How to find my IDLE's Python, and then apply pip upgrade to a package it uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54798448/3904031) as it's too old to migrate. Once I receive an answer there and it works, I'll add the answer here as well.

Comment: Your comment dies not match the question  question awakes how to update packages in conda with pop comment is about non cons packages. Please clarify.

Comment: @Mark I'm sorry but I don't understand your comment. In both questions I've asked how to use pip to update a package used by the python that my IDLE installation uses, *not the one that anaconda uses*.